# Trying to achieve easing transform through css only - jumpy

Tags: html, css, transform

I am trying to make a grid that on hover increases in size. 
It does exactly what I want it to do, but its jumpy. I dont want it to jump like this.
Is there something I am doing extremely wrong?

I think its the margin-top and bottoms that are messing it. Does anyone have suggestions how to fix this?

Here is the [JSBin](http://jsbin.com/jarizowo/1/edit?html,css,console,output)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't use margins, use some newer css techniques and slim this down. It doesn't jump around. However, other stuff on the page will shift.

**http://jsbin.com/jarizowo/2/edit**

```
.cf:before,
.cf:after {
    content: " "; /* 1 */
    display: table; /* 2 */
}

.cf:after {
    clear: both
}

.grid,
.grid * {
    box-sizing: border-box
}

.grid > .col img {
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
}

.col {
    width: 25%;
    float: left;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
    padding: 3px;
}

.col:hover {
    width: 48%
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="grid cf">
 <div class="col">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRxMWdIL1mxF_PJHJi-PUUnbSnfOtO1eQPa3AxRAyiCEZBnXXSX">
 </div>
 <!--col-->
 <div class="col">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS4fExlS5dZ69n_H0Ci_a6RATh_rRjEw1Ac2yTdg-R8EcxNW7iE">
 </div>
</div>
<div class="grid cf">
 <div class="col">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRxMWdIL1mxF_PJHJi-PUUnbSnfOtO1eQPa3AxRAyiCEZBnXXSX">
 </div>
 <!--col-->
 <div class="col">
  <img src="https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcS4fExlS5dZ69n_H0Ci_a6RATh_rRjEw1Ac2yTdg-R8EcxNW7iE">
 </div>
</div>
```

Comment: agreed- but this isnt doing what i need it to do. Although it looks good too. but the grid needs to be on center of the page (max width 960px;) and only on hover shows these effects. Plus it still pushes down other content. Is there no other way to do what I am trying to achieve?

Comment: This is something to start with or try to look for a jQuery solution. You will need use a wrapper and correct percentages. http://jsbin.com/ziqak/2/edit

Comment: Thanks for  being rude atleast after helping me. I do not understand why people who know their way around coding are always so impatient and rude. I took a long time to try this one before asking about it. Css is not one of my weak points.

Comment: Sorry you think I was rude, I was being quick, since this is unpaid and time consuming. There's absolutely no emotions on my part. There's nothing to work with but your question and the bin, and your mentioning of margins.

Comment: No problem thanks for all your Time. I am using your method I figured out a way to center it for my need. Thanks for whatever you did.